# how to reset the image bounding box after clipping the image in fabric js v 5.3.0

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric JS 5.3.0

and after I clip an image the bounding box (width/height) image is still the original and not equal to the clipped image

What i have tried

i tried setting the image width and height to the cropping box width and height it kind of work i am the bonding box is correct but i moved the clip-path to the top left of the image

MY CODE

```
  enterCroppingMode() {
            let obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

            this.isCropping = true;

            currentElement = obj;


            croppingBox = new useFabric.Rect({
                left: obj.getBoundingRect().left + 10,
                top: obj.getBoundingRect().top + 10,
                width: obj.getScaledWidth(),
                height: obj.getScaledHeight(),
                fill: "rgba(0,0,0,.3)",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                stroke: "#777",
                strokeUniform: true,
                noScaleCache: false,
                isCropBox: true
            });

            canvas.croppingBoxLeft = croppingBox.left;

            canvas.add(croppingBox);

            canvas.setActiveObject(croppingBox);


            canvas.renderAll();
        },
        cropImage() {
            canvas.setActiveObject(currentElement);

            let obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

            this.selection = obj;
            
            clipPath = new fabric.Rect({
                left: -croppingBox.getScaledWidth(),
                top: -croppingBox.getScaledHeight(),
                width: croppingBox.getScaledWidth() * 2,
                height: croppingBox.getScaledHeight() * 2
            });

            obj.clipPath = clipPath;

            canvas.remove(croppingBox);

            croppingBox = false;
            currentElement = false;
            clipPath = false;
            this.isCropping = false;

           canvas.renderAll()
           
        },
```

[image: BEFORE CROPPED]

[image: AFTER CROPPED]